# Using RequireJS in an Azure deployment file

Tags: node.js, azure, cmd, requirejs

We have been using RequireJS Optimizer in our deployment file for months now. Everything was working.

Basically what we are doing is the following:

We compile our Coffee scripts files

```
node %DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\build\node_modules\coffee-script\bin\coffee -co "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\src\Web\Scripts" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\src\Web\Coffee"
```

Then we opitmize the js files into a single file using RequireJS:

```
node "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\build\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js" -o "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\build\build.js"
```

Locally, it works #1. But on Azure we have this error:

```
Cannot optimize network URL, skipping: //1.1.1.1.1/path/site/repository/src/Web/Scripts/dashboard/almond.js
```

Please note that I changed the IP and the paths.

I checked the documentation of RequireJS, and in fact it does not support network URLs when optimizing.

The same script was working a few days ago.

Anybody aware of changes in Azure that could have lead to this? Any workaround?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it working by overriding the baseUrl when calling r.js:

```
node "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\build\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js" -o "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\build\build.js" baseUrl=%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\src\Web\scripts
```